# Eloquent - modify standard with() response for a particular model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a bunch of stuff I do in a closure whenever a relationship is brought in using the `with()` Eloquent method, and I'm having to repeat this code an awful lot:

```
        'earmarks' => function($q) {
            $q
            ->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'earmarks.location')
            ->select('earmarks.*', 'locations.location AS em_location')
            ->orderBy('date', 'asc');
        }
```

Since I always want to do the above whenever `with()` is called on that relationship, how can I add it to my model so it gets added automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract the callback function to a [Query Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes) or make a totally new relationship for earmarks with that query.

```
public function earmarksWithLocations()
{
    return $this->earmarks()
        ->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'earmarks.location')
        ->select('earmarks.*', 'locations.location AS em_location')
        ->orderBy('date', 'asc');
}


->with('earmarksWithLocations')
```

or

```
public function scopeWithLocations($q)
{
    return $q
        ->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'earmarks.location')
        ->select('earmarks.*', 'locations.location AS em_location')
        ->orderBy('date', 'asc');
}


->with(['earmarks' => function ($q) {
    $q->withLocations();
}])
```